# uidevice takescreenshot option to compress file not working

Tags: java, android, junit, android-uiautomator

I am using UI Automator to take low resolution screenshot using below commands in Junit test. All four screenshots are of same size. I expect it to be compressed. Let me know if anyone else was able to successfully implement it. I would like to get just get thumbnails of screen, instead of high resolution screenshot. Suggest alternate ways if available.

```
getUiDevice().takeScreenshot(new File("/sdcard/Pictures/"+"test1.png"));
getUiDevice().takeScreenshot(new File("/sdcard/Pictures/"+"test2.png"),0.1f,10);
getUiDevice().takeScreenshot(new File("/sdcard/Pictures/"+"test3.png"),0.2f,20);
getUiDevice().takeScreenshot(new File("/sdcard/Pictures/"+"test4.png"),1.0f,20);
```

Android Reference for UI Automator API

> TakeScreenshot
>
> boolean takeScreenshot (File storePath, 
>                   float scale, 
>                   int quality) Take a screenshot of current window and store it as PNG The screenshot is adjusted per screen rotation
>
> Parameters storePath  File: where the PNG should be written to
>   scale float: scale the screenshot down if needed; 1.0f for original
>   size quality  int: quality of the PNG compression; range: 0-100

Answer (score 1):

This is the implementation of `takeScreenshot` in `UiDevice.java`:

```
/**
 * Take a screenshot of current window and store it as PNG
 *
 * The screenshot is adjusted per screen rotation
 *
 * @param storePath where the PNG should be written to
 * @param scale scale the screenshot down if needed; 1.0f for original size
 * @param quality quality of the PNG compression; range: 0-100
 * @return true if screen shot is created successfully, false otherwise
 * @since API Level 17
 */
public boolean takeScreenshot(File storePath, float scale, int quality) {
    Tracer.trace(storePath, scale, quality);
    return getAutomatorBridge().takeScreenshot(storePath, quality);
}
```

As you can see `scale` is not used at all and `quality` is only used to set the quality of the PNG saved.